# Customized checkboxes are not clickable in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid with checkbox selection column and I customized these checkboxes but now checkboxes are not clickable, cannot be unchecked or checked

How do I solve this?

Here is my code

```
@( Html.Kendo().Grid<MockUpForeNet.Controllers.CardDetailController.Days>()
     .Name("timegrid")
     .DataSource(d => d.Ajax().Read("TimeGridBinding", "CardDetail").Model(keys =>
     {
         keys.Id(k => k.DayId);
         keys.Field(c => c.DayName).Editable(false);
         keys.Field(c => c.DayId).Editable(false);
     }).PageSize(7))
               .Columns(c =>
               {
                   c.Bound(p => p.DayId).Width(100).Title(" ").ClientTemplate("#= chk2(data) #").Sortable(false);
                   c.Bound(e => e.DayName).Width("auto").Title("Day");
               })
       .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.InCell))
       .Sortable()
       .ColumnMenu()
)
```

here my checkbox template

```
function chk2(data) {
    return '<input id="masterCheck' + data.DayId + '" class="k-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><label for="masterCheck" class="k-checkbox-label"></label>';
}
```

Comment: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/checkbox-selection

Comment: @GaloisGirl I'm not using columns.Select() i'm using client template but still not clickable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your template: `label for="masterCheck"` is missing `data.DayId` .

Also note that checkboxes have [changed in version 2020.1.114](https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/kendo-ui-r1-2020) and don't need the empty label anymore. See examples on https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/checkbox/index . Remember to provide an `aria-label` for accessibility reasons.

Comment: LOL! Thanks! I missed that

Comment: can you help me on this 2 question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60411526/kendo-grid-inline-combobox-not-changing-value/60412692#60412692 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60426643/kendo-grid-inline-edit-kendo-timepicker-not-changing-value

Answer (score 0):

`DayId` should be made editable in the `DataSource`

```
keys.Field(c => c.DayId).Editable(true);
```

Comment: No because that value is integer and masked with checkbox when its editable true and click on it so it shows textbox