# Kendo Grid Inline combobox not changing value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have kendo mvc grid with inline edition. I want to edit my values in grid but when i click on combobox value and change it. It's not changing row value return old existing value

How can i solve this?

Here my grid and Template

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MockUpForeNet.Controllers.CardDetailController.Limits>()
        .Name("limitgrid").AutoBind(true)
        .DataSource(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
        .Read("GridLimitBinding", "CardDetail",new { rule = rule }).Update("UpdateLimit", "Transaction")
        .Model(keys =>
        {
            keys.Id(c => c.Id);
            keys.Field(c => c.Id).Editable(false);
            keys.Field("DurationType", typeof(string)).Editable(true);
            keys.Field("DurationValue", typeof(string)).Editable(true);
            keys.Field("ValueType", typeof(string)).Editable(true);
            keys.Field("MaxValue", typeof(string)).Editable(true);

        }).Batch(true).ServerOperation(false)
        )
        .Events(e => e.DataBound("hidecolumn1"))
        .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.InCell))
        .ToolBar(commands =>
        {
            commands.Create().Text(" ");
            commands.Save().SaveText(" ").CancelText(" ");
        })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.MaxValue).Width(200).Title("Limit").ClientTemplate("#= ValueType == 'Amount' ? Row(MaxValue) : RowLiters(MaxValue) #");
            columns.Bound(e => e.ValueType).Width(200).Title("Type").EditorTemplateName("ValueType");
            columns.Bound(e => e.DurationValue).Width(200).Title("Duration");
            columns.Bound(e => e.DurationType).Width(200).Title("Duration Type").EditorTemplateName("DurationType");
            columns.Bound(e => e.Id).Visible(false);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Id).Width(80).ClientTemplate("<img src='../../assets/images/icons/delete.svg' id='#=Id#' />").Filterable(false).IncludeInMenu(false).Title(" ");
        })
        //.Selectable()
        .Sortable()
        .Navigatable(configurator => configurator.Enabled(true))



         ///My template
          @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                .Name("cbvaltype").ValuePrimitive(true)
                .Items(i =>
                {
                    i.Add().Text("Quantity").Value("Quantity");
                    i.Add().Text("Amount").Value("Amount");
                })
            )
```

Comment: Looking at your `Template`. Shouldn't that then call a method to get the values for the combobox?

Comment: @JamesS like what??

Comment: Please see my answer. You will/ may need to edit your code to accompany how the comboBox works

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would create a comboBox in kendo like this:

The column in which the comboBox box is located (Nothing has changed here):

```
columns.Bound(e => e.ValueType).Width(200).Title("Type").EditorTemplateName("ValueType");
```

The template:

```
@model // The model of the comboBox (Which as I have stated below should be `ValueType`)

        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m)
            .HtmlAttributes(new {data_skip = "true", data_bind = "defferedValue: ValueType"})
            .PlaceHolder("Select a value")
            .DataSource(source => 
            {
                source.Read("GetValues", "//Controller").ServerFiltering();
            })
            .MinLength(3)
            .AutoBind(false)
            .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
            .DataValueField("ValueID")
            .DataTextField("ValueText")
        )
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetValues(string text)
{
    List<ValueModel> valueList = new List<ValueModel>();

    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)){
        valueList = //Get a list of values which you want to be in this list (ie what you want to show in the comboBox)

        // Above you should also do some LINQ to query against the list and get the correct values (ie .Where(x => x.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower())).ToList())
    }

    return Json(valueList, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet)
}
```

So, what are we doing above?

I have changed the template to accept a model class and we have edited the comboBox from a ComboBox to a ComboBoxFor. This uses the model passed into the view.

```
        .DataValueField("ValueID")
        .DataTextField("ValueText")
```

Are essentially the ID and text of the comboxBox.

NOTE: I believe, if not already, you should change `ValueType` variable to be a class called `ValueType` or whatever and that class should be define such as the following:

```
public class ValueType
{
    public int ValueID{get;set;}
    public string ValueText{get;set;}
}
```

`MinLength(3)` specifies that the user needs to type a minimum of 3 characters to start the comboBox search.

We call a controller method `GetValues` which accepts the parameter `text` and in here we check to make sure `text` is not null or empty and then return the values from a list of `ValueType`'s where the Valuetext ToLower() contains the text passed into the function.

We then return that to the template which then sets the value in the grid.

Comment: But i guess you understand me wrong my problem is not binding items in combobox my problem is when i change value in combobox in grid i cannot see changed value it returned to old value @JamesS